# performSelector not working when create selector from string

Tags: ios, performselector

I'm creating selector from string:

```
NSString *seleccion = [NSString new];

seleccion = (NSString*)[self.detailItem description];
SEL methodToSelect = NSSelectorFromString(seleccion);
if ([self respondsToSelector:methodToSelect])
{
    NSLog(@"the method exist");
    [self performSelector:methodToSelect withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}
```

But the method is never executed.

I tried, this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod)];
```

and it work just fine.

I'm using :

```
[self performSelector:methodToSelect withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

because if I use

```
[self performSelector:methodToSelect];
```

I get this warning "PerfomSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown"

I'll really appreciate your help or any pointers of how to make this works.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Are you sure [self.detailItem description] is returning a string that's the name of a method you implemented? Is "the method exist" being logged to the console? By the way, your first line, NSString *seleccion = [NSString new];, is unnecessary, since you assign seleccion to something else in the next line.

Comment: The reason I have this "if ([self respondsToSelector:methodToSelect])" it's to verify the selector exist.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you then, because it worked fine for me. Without knowing what [self.detailItem description] returned, and what you did in the implementation of the method pointed to by that selector, I can't offer any help. What is the nature of detailItem? Is it a string?

Answer (score 0):

`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` does *not* run the method immediately. It runs it *asynchronously* on the run loop of the current thread. If this is not on the main thread, then there is no run loop running unless you explicitly started it. Also, if your application is not a run loop based application, it will also not have a run loop.

Comment: I was using [self performSelector:methodToSelect]; but I was getting this warning: "I get this warning "PerfomSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown". Do you know a work around this?

Comment: @user2924482: just suppress the warning if you know that it's not a selector that starts with `new`, `alloc`, `retain`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`.